# Magic++ RGB colors values

Tags: c++, image-processing

Does anyone know why is Magic++ giving me RGB values less than 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum RGB component value in Magick is 1 and the minimum is 0. So the values should be between 0 and 1. For example, RGB values of (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) represents a grey, (1.0, 0, 0) would be a pure red, etc.

Check out the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html). You may also find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) of interest, it discusses what typically happens when the RGB component values are between 0 and 1 (multiplied by 255).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that specific library but RGBs are commonly represented as floating point values between 0 and 1 as well as unsigned byte values between 0 and 255.